# How to get user timeline using fabric?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

i'm trying to develop a Twitter App using Fabric. I have looked Fabric documentation(http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-timelines.html) and i integrated code to my application.But i couldn't get a result. In main activity i can login using Twitter account after i want to redirect activity to timeline activity.However on the other activity which is redirected there doesn't seem anything. What is my wrong ? Here is my code.
Thanks!

MainActivity.xml

```
<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
    android:id="@+id/twitter_login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Succeed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             Intent timeLine = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Timeline.class); 
             startActivity(timeLine);

        }
```

Timeline.xml

```
<TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="No Tweets"/>

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="#e1e8ed"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

Timeline.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeline);

        final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
                .screenName("fabric")
                .build();
        final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
                .setTimeline(userTimeline)
                .build();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `Timeline.java` you can search the user timeline:

```
private static final String SEARCH_QUERY = "almounir"; //the user name

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout. activity_timeline);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.loading)); d'ont forget to add loading pic 

    SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder().query(SEARCH_QUERY).build();

    final TweetTimelineListAdapter timelineAdapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter(this, searchTimeline);

    lv.setAdapter(timelineAdapter);
}
```

i hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Timeline activity still doesn't show anything.Can the reason be about Search_Query ?

Comment: i'm using this on my App.. is your "Timeline.java" extending ListActivity if yes please change it to Activity, then in "Timeline.xml" in <ListView android:id="@id/android:list" change it to android:id="@+id/list"